# Как сделать прямоугольные блоки в Viewpager2?

Tags: java, android, xml

пытаюсь сделать как в google pay перелистывание карт, как на картинке и вторая картинка что у меня получается. Использую ViewPage2 ,но не получается сделать именно такой вид. Не понимаю как сделать, помогите пожалуйста.

[image: как должно быть]
[image: как получается]

Вот адаптер:

```
public class SliderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SliderAdapter.SliderViewHolder> {
 
    private List<SliderItem> sliderItems;
    HashMap<SliderItem, String> map;
    private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    private RoundedImageView constraintLayout;
    private Activity itemView;
    private Context mContext;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
 
    SliderAdapter(List<SliderItem> sliderItems, ViewPager2 viewPager2, HashMap<SliderItem, String> map, Context context) {
        this.sliderItems = sliderItems;
        this.map = map;
        this.viewPager2 = viewPager2;
        this.mContext = context;
 
    }
 
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SliderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new SliderViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.slide_item_container,
                        parent,
                        false
                )
        );
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SliderViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        holder.bind(sliderItems.get(position));
        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               SliderItem item=sliderItems.get(position);
 
 
                        BitMatrix bitMatrix = null;
 
                        try {
                            bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(item.getCode(), BarcodeFormat.EAN_13, 400, 170, null);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            try {
                                bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(item.getCode(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 500, 500, null);
                            } catch (Exception Exception) {
 
                                return;
                            }
                        }
 
                        BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                        Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                        Log.d("rerer", String.valueOf(bitmap));
                        final BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
                        View bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, (ViewGroup) bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_content));
                        ImageView imageView = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.code_sheet);
                        TextView textView = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.NameCard);
                TextView textView2 = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.code_scan);
                        ImageView imageView1=bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.delete_image);
                        imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
 
 
                            }
                        });
                        textView2.setText(item.getCode());
                        textView.setText(item.getName());
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 
                        bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
                        bottomSheetDialog.show();
 
 
 
 
            }
        });
    }
 
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sliderItems.size();
    }
 
    class SliderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
       private LinearLayout linearLayout;
       private ImageView imageView;
    //    private RoundedImageView imageView;
          private TextView textView;
        SliderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
      //      linearLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.linner);
            imageView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_back);
            textView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_slider);
        }
      public void bind(SliderItem sliderItem){
           imageView.setBackgroundResource(Math.toIntExact(sliderItem.getImage()));
            textView.setText(sliderItem.getName());
      }
 
    }
}
```

Xml контейнер для списка:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
 
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
 
        <ImageView
 
            android:id="@+id/image_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gradirnt"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
 
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_slider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Карта"
            android:textColor="#F1F0F0"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 
 
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Сам ViewPage:

```
       android:id="@+id/viewPagerImageSlider"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="104dp"

       android:paddingStart="100dp"
       android:paddingEnd="100dp"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

В основном коде иницилизация:

```
 viewPager2.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(sliderItems, viewPager2, map, CardActivity.this));
                 viewPager2.setClipToPadding(false);
                 viewPager2.setClipChildren(false);
                 viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
                 viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
 
 
                 CompositePageTransformer compositePageTransformer = new CompositePageTransformer();
                 compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new MarginPageTransformer(150));
                 // Растояние между картами
                 compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(new ViewPager2.PageTransformer() {
                     @Override
                     public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
                         float r = 1 - Math.abs(position);
                         page.setScaleY(0.85f + r * 0.15f);
                     }
                 });
 
                 viewPager2.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer);
             }
         });
```

И фон:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >
<size android:width="600dp"
    android:height="200dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FF0000"
        android:endColor="#00FF00"
        android:angle="225">
    </gradient>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У вас padding слишком большой (100dp)
2. Вы не установили `android:clipToPadding="false"`

Попробуйте вот эту

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerImageSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingStart="24dp"
        android:paddingEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: viewPager2.setClipToPadding(false) вот же в основном коде выставлял это значение программно

Comment: И что вы имеете ввиду под набивкой

Comment: Действительно помог ваш ответ и всё стало как нужно, но ещё есть вопрос как уменьшить расстояние между ними

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду расстояние между картами, то уменьшите padding ещё. Например с 24dp на 8dp

Comment: Последний вопрос, а как тогда сделать так чтоб было видно следующую карту